# Access Class in Class from another Script?

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine

first of all I'm a rookie in Unity3D and especally in programming. At this moment i try diffrent things and study different documentations to create an economy simulation game.
So please be merciful to me if i dont understand your solutions instantly ;)

I need to access a twodimensional List from another script.
In Script1 I use a Class to make the 2D

```
public class OrderArray : MonoBehaviour
{

    List<Order> orders;

    public class Order
    {
        public string company{ get; set; }
        public string date{ get; set; }
        public int quantity{ get; set; }
        public string deliverdate{ get; set; }
    }
    void Start()
    {
        orders= new List<Order>();

        orders.Add(new Order
        {   company = "Woodpecker Corp",
            date = "21.11.2014",
            quantity= 250,
            deliverdate= "29.11.2014" });



        // To access the Data in the list Im using:
        Order order1= orders[0];;
        Debug.Log(order1.company)
    }
```

So far so good. Script1 runs good for me.

Now how can I access "order1.company" for example from a different Script on the same GameObject?

I knwo how I can access the variable in Script1 und Class Script in generall but I cant make it to accsess the variables in class "Order".

My result of Script2 till now

```
public class menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    OrderArray orderarray;
    Orderarray.Order orderclass;

    void start()
    {
        orderarray= gameObject.GetComponent<OrderArray>();
    }
```

Now I have access to the class OrderArray but I dont know how can i access the class Order inside OrderArray.

Maybe you could give me an approuch to solution or an example code I can transfer for my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your OrderArray with a GetOrderByIndex method:

```
public Order GetOrderByIndex(int index){
  return orders[index];
}
```

You could use it in your start like this:

```
   void start()
     {
         orderarray= gameObject.GetComponent<OrderArray>();
         Order order1 = orderarray.GetOrderByIndex(0);
         //do what you want with order1
     }
```

Comment: could you give me a concrete example how could i access the class then?

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like Mark Smit mentioned is probably best. One thing you should consider though is making "Order" a struct instead of a class since it doesn't hold a whole lot of data and you'll have a bunch of them I'd imagine. For further information take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx). And add a constructor to "Order" for easier creation of a new one ->

```
new Order("Woodpecker Corp", "21.11.2014", 250, "29.11.2014")
```